# Proving 3 functions combined are injective

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given: 
$f: A \to B$
$h: B \to B$
$g: A \to A$
$g$ and $h$ are injective and onto. If $f$ is injective, how should I go around proving that $h\circ f\circ g$ is injective?

Comment: Do you already know that the combination of *two* injectives is injective?

Comment: The composition of injections is an injection since one of the definitions of ‘injective’ is that different elements have different images

Comment: Thanks. And what about the other side? h○f○g is injective and i need to prove f is injective?

Answer (score 0):

You can prove this using the cardinalities of your sets.

If f is injective, then $|A| \le |B|$

If h is injective and onto (therefore bijective), then $|B| = |B|$

If g is injective and onto (therefore bijective), then $|A| = |A|$

if h○f○g is defined as $:A \rightarrow B \rightarrow B$

we can rearrange our inequalities to show

$|A| \le |B| = |B|$

and our composite function is injective.